# How do we know gravitational lensing is caused by gravity and not by a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravitational-lensing

Is it possible that other factors could be contributing to the lensing effects we observe, particularly magnetic field disruptions?

Light has a frequency, and my understanding is that a magnet can distort that by introducing other frequencies.

Thank you, and sorry if my question shows great ignorance!  I know very little.

Comment: Light does not interact with magnetic fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnetic fields only affect the trajectories of charged particles. Photons have no charge, so light is not deflected nor is its frequency changed by any magnetic fields that we can produce on Earth. If it was, we would see optical effects around magnets, electric motors, MRI machines etc.

It is possible that light is affected by the immensely strong magnetic fields around [magnetars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar), but these are small compared to a galaxy and are not on a big enough scale to produce the deflections that we see in gravitational lensing.